# Route 53 Amazon DNS lookup fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, lookup, amazon-route53

I recently ported my website from shared hosting to AWS. I'm using an Elastic Load Balancer connected to my instances, which are running my website, shopyoke.com. Ever since the website has been ported, some people reported that the website's DNS lookup failed:

[image]

Some people report that the scripts and stylesheets failed to load (which are hosted on CloudFront):

[image]

While some people report that everything is working perfectly! I double and triple checked that the nameservers on GoDaddy are entered accurately to what Route 53 specified. Here's what my Route 53 DNS config looks like:

[image]

I tried all the DNS tests and they all returned a healthy status. I tried a ping test but that shows 100% packet loss:

[image]

I'm really I can't think of any way to resolve this issue since it's so inconsistent among so many people.

Comment: How recently did you port your site to use Route53? These sorts of behaviors can easily be attributed to lag in switching DNS.  Some ISP's are notorious for being slow to update DNS servers for domains.  Also, ELB's don't respond to ping, so that explains your last comment.

Comment: @BruceP does this same time lag exist when you procure a domain name from Route 53 itself and then point that to an EC2 instance? I created the instance and purchased the address from Route 53 and pointed it to the Public DNS and IP of the EC2 instance about 14 hours ago and I am still receiving a "DNS lookup failed" error.

Answer (score 12):

OK.  It took me a day to finally figure this out, after much despair and frustration.

The gist of the issue is, the name servers defined in my "hosted zone"  and the name servers as defined in my domain registration (with Route53 as the registrar), do not match.  THEY NEED TO MATCH.  In fact, AWS has this to say underneath the 4 name servers:

- Before the Domain Name System will start to route queries for this domain to Route 53 name servers, you must update the name server records either with the current DNS service or with the registrar for the domain, as applicable.

This is very important.  Here is what needs to be done:

Copy these 4 servers from the area of "hosted zones" into a text editor, for use later.

And then, on the left hand pane, click on "registered domains".  A list of registered domains will show up.  In my case, there is only one.  Click on the name of the domain, and you will get to review the properties of the domain currently registered, including, on the right side, this ---> name servers.

In my case, this list of name servers is different from the one under the hosted zone above.

I need to click on "Add or Edit Name Servers".  I need to override all the entries with the ones earlier that I have saved in my text editor.  I copied and pasted from there into here.  Clicked on "update".  After a few minutes, I get an email from AWS Route 53, acknowledging and confirming that I had made such a modification request.  And upon refreshing the window, the name server list has indeed been updated.

And my Route 53 is now working!

This is Sean Shen and can be contacted via seantshen@gmail.com, in case anybody has questions on this.  I will be glad to help.